Realising a $K$-point on a curve as a morphism of schemes
Let $E$ be a curve whose equations have coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. Say we are looking at projective solutions to the equations in a number field $K$ and denote the set of solutions as $E(K)$. I first learned that saying $(x:y:z)$ is a point on $E$ means $x,y,z$ satisfies the equations and if $(x:y:z)\in E(K)$, then we can find a nonzero scalar $\lambda$ in say, $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z$ are in $K$.
Then I learned another definition that said a $K$-point of $E$ is an arrow $\mathrm{Spec}K\to E$. Since $E$ sits in $\mathbb{P}^{2}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ which can be covered by three affine patches $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{A}^{3}_{\mathbb{Q}}:x\ne0\}$, $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{A}^{3}_{\mathbb{Q}}:y\ne0\}$, and $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{A}^{3}_{\mathbb{Q}}:z\ne0\}$, then the point $\mathrm{Spec}K$ must map to one of these three patches, say the first patch where $x\ne0$. Then we can write $\mathrm{Spec}K\to Z$ as $\mathrm{Spec}K\to\mathrm{Spec}A$ where $A=\mathbb{Q}[Y,Z]/\frak{a}$ and $\frak{a}$ is the ideal generated by the polynomials defining $E$ dehomogenised with respect to $x$ and $Y=\frac{y}{x}$ and $Z=\frac{z}{x}$. We can then consider the corresponding $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphism\begin{align*}\mathbb{Q}[Y,Z]/\frak{a}&\to K\\\overline{Y}&\mapsto\beta\\\overline{Z}&\mapsto\gamma\end{align*}If we had a point $(\beta,\gamma)$ satisfying the dehomogenised equations defining $E$, then we would be able to define a homomorphism. So whether or not there is an arrow $\mathrm{Spec} K\to E$ aligns with whether or not there is such an affine point $(\beta,\gamma)$ (or projective point $(1:\beta:\gamma)$) satisfying the equations.
So this gives me a way to go from the arrow interpretation to the coordinates interpretation of a $K$-point. Now say I start with a point $(a:b:c)$ in $E(K)$ where $a\ne0$, and I want to define a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphism from this.
Would it just be the same homomorphism above? I thought it might not be well-defined at first because $(a:b:c)$ is the same as $(\lambda a:\lambda b:\lambda c)$, so we might have several homomorphisms per point, but if I plug in the $\lambda$ into all the variables, then I think it cancels out so it's the same homomorphism, but I thought maybe not since the polynomial could have a constant. Maybe I'm completely wrong on how to define this. Then once I have this homomorphism, I would like to define an arrow $\mathrm{Spec}K\to E$ from it.
Another question I had was what if I take this point $(a:b:c)$ and wanted to write the homomorphism corresponding to say, $(a-b:-b:c)$. But I think if I know how to go from coordinates to arrows in general, then that may answer this question.
Finally, I wanted to consider the case of when we replace $\mathrm{Spec}K$ with any $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme $S$. Using the arrow interpretation, let $(S\stackrel{x}{\to}E)$, $(S\stackrel{y}{\to}E)$ be in $E(S)$. Since $E(S)$ is algebraic group, then we can add the points. I would like to know how to think about how to add points when regarding points as morphisms.
I know these are a lot of questions, my main question was trying to go from a point with coordinates to a morphism $S\to E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$-schemes. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.
